# Call Oracle stored procedure from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I Have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UpdateFileMapping(field in number, original_Field_Names in DBMS_SQL.varChar2_table, mapped_Field_Ids in DBMS_SQL.number_table)
IS 
C NUMBER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
N NUMBER;
BEGIN
DBMS_SQL.PARSE(C,'INSERT INTO input_file_mapping VALUES(input_file_mapping_id.NextVal, 3, field, :fieldName, :mappedFieldId)', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

DBMS_SQL.BIND_ARRAY(C,':fieldName', original_Field_Names);
DBMS_SQL.BIND_ARRAY(C,':mappedFieldId', mapped_Field_Ids);
N := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(C);
DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(C);
END;
```

How to call such procedure which takes as input of `DBMS_SQL.varChar2_table` type from C#?

Comment: So you totally have no C# code to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure UpdateFileMapping(m in Number,y in    DBMS_SQL.varChar2_table,z in DBMS_SQL.number_table)
IS  
C NUMBER;
N NUMBER;

BEGIN

C := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
DBMS_SQL.PARSE(C,'INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(:x  ,:fieldName,:mappedFieldId)',DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
 DBMS_SQL.BIND_ARRAY(C,':fieldName',original_Field_Names);
DBMS_SQL.BIND_ARRAY(C,':mappedFieldId',mapped_Field_Ids);
DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(C,':x',file_Id);
N := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(C);
DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(C);

END;
```

For more information:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the proper [ODP.NET provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) for your system and then use `OracleConnection` and `OracleCommand` types to create a connection and execute the stored procedure. ODP.NET comes with extensive documentation and [many examples](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/extenRest.htm).

Comment: Why don't just use `System.Data.OracleClient` ?

Comment: Because [it's deprecated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
void ExecOracleStoredProcedure(int field, string[] original_Field_Names, int[] mapped_Field_Ids)
{
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "UpdateFileMapping";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":field").Value = field;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":original_Field_Names").Value = original_Field_Names;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":mapped_Field_Ids").Value = mapped_Field_Ids;

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is throeing exception "wrong datatype or not sufficient argument";

Comment: @Niraj: Try specify correct data types via `command.Parameters.Add()`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5ReleaseNotes) from MS still support Oracle Database

For the Data Access Application Block, the following is also required:

> A database server running a database that is supported by a .NET Framework 3.5 with Service Pack 1 or .NET Framework 4.0 data provider. This includes SQL Server® 2000 or later, SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition, and Oracle 9i or later. The database server can also run a database that is supported by the .NET Framework 3.5 with Service Pack 1 or the .NET Framework 4.0 data providers for OLE DB or ODBC.